# Why putting bloc providers in a separate file/class throws an error?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-provider, flutter-bloc

I have this code:

```dart
MultiBlocProvider(
  providers: [
    BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => CubitExample(),
    ),
  ],
  child: MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
  ),
);
```

It's working fine, I have many cubits/blocs so I decided to move the providers list to a separate class:

```dart
MultiBlocProvider(
  providers: BlocProviders.blocs(),
  child: MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
  ),
);
```

---

```dart
// The class 
class BlocProviders {
  static List<BlocProvider> blocs() {
    return <BlocProvider>[
      BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => CubitExample(()),
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```

Now the usual bloc error is thrown:

```
ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ExampleCubit> above this BlocBuilder<ExampleCubit, ExampleState> Widget
```

I don't know why the error is thrown when I try the second code, why the error is thrown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I managed to get some insights,

Whenever we wrap a widget with `MultiBlocProvider`, we give the list of Providers in it with a child widget.

So I looked into the implementation of `MultiBlocProvider` and I found that it accepts a List of type **BlocProviderSingleChildWidget** and it is a mixin defined on `SingleChildWidget`  which means that we can not use List.

Now in your case you defined the widget class like this:

```js
MultiBlocProvider(
  providers: BlocProviders.blocs(),
  child: MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
  ),
);
```

and your bloc class like this:

```js
class BlocProviders {
  static List<BlocProvider> blocs() {
    return <BlocProvider>[
      BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => CubitExample(()),
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```

In this you have created list of type `List<BlocProvider>`, which is not a `BlocProviderSingleChildWidget`. Therefore it was showing you the error you were talking about.

One person answered the question by using the `getter` method  instead of static function, and it was working because he didn't give any type to the list(it was dynamic), therefore the error was gone.

Now, If you want to use your class and functions like you've mentioned, you can pretty much use it by giving it dynmic type like this:

```js
class BlocProviders {
  static blocs() {
    return [
      BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => CubitExample(),
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```

Hope it solved all your issues and question related to it. Further, if you want to know about it you can look at the implementation of `MultiBlocProvider`.

Comment: Yes, this is related to the way the BloC library is implemented, the reason for this behavior id the Type I set, Thank you for clarifying it.

Answer (score 3):

It is really strange why this is behaving this way!!, I tried all possible work arounds.

Finally found a way around to this by using `getter`.
Replace your `function` with `getter`. This should do the work.

```
class Providers {
  static get getproviders => [
        ...  all your providers here
        ),
      ];
}
```

And call it as

```
 MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: Providers.getproviders,  Call it here
        child: MaterialApp.router(
         ...
   ));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes it is strange and what I want to know is what's the difference between the codes I wrote.

Comment: Yes.., me too would like to know the same. I'll get back to you on this.